# How can I convert below sql to QueryDSL code?

Tags: querydsl

I'm testing QueryDSL.
How can I convert below sql to QueryDSL code?

```
select c.*
,(
    select count(*)
    from project_category_map m
    , project p
    where 1=1
    and m.category_id = c.category_id
    and m.project_id = p.project_id
) as project_count
from category c
```

Comment: Do you use Querydsl with SQL, JPA or something else?

Comment: yes, i do. but i don't know to write querydsl code when scala sub query(calculated column) case.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Tuple> tuple(Category category) {
    QProjectCategoryMap qProjectCategoryMap = QProjectCategoryMap.projectCategoryMap;
    QProject qProject = QProject.qProject;

    return
        this.queryFactory
            .select(this.qCategory,
                SQLExpressions
                    .select(qProject.count())
                    .from(qProjectCategoryMap)
                    .join(qProject)
                    .where(qProjectCategoryMap.categoryId.eq(qCategory.categoryId))
                    .where(qProject.projectId.eq(qProjectCategoryMap.projectId))
            )
            .from(this.qCategory)
            .fetch();
}
```

Comment: "this.qCategory" is undefined.